# Rails Path Helper for Root should output "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my routes file, I have a resource called products. The index action of the products resource is also my root path.

```
resources :products
root :to => "products#index"
```

When I use the helper method products_path (in a redirect or link), it returns "/products". But what I want is for it to return "/".  I know it's the same page, but I want to keep my URL's consistent.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
root :to => 'products#index', :as => :products
match '', :to => 'products#index', :as => :root  # recreate named root_path, if you use it anywhere
```

This will need to appear below your `resources :products` as it does in your example above. This will override the `products_path` and `products_url` you'd get from `resources`. Run `rake routes` before and after to compare.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to change Index try excluding it first then defining it on its own like so:

```
resources :products, :except => [:index]
resources :products, :only => [:index], :path => '/'
```

Comment: This is a good answer because it leaves you with one canonical route for your resource. It's not a great idea to have multiple urls hit the same page, it can hurt seo, confuse stat tracking etc...

Comment: I thought this was working at first, but it seems to be screwing up some other routes. My create action stopped working. Hmmm...

Comment: should not really affect the create action at all as the routing for that is unchanged.  what problem are you having exactly?

Comment: I noticed that one of my tests stopped working (for creating a new product). I did some debugging and found that submitting the New Product form was never hitting the create method of my products controller. As soon as I changed back my routes file, it worked fine. Very weird.

Comment: strange indeed.  not sure what would cause that but just restart the server and try again if you havent already.  if worst comes to worst another option to force that to work would be to specify ':url => { :action => 'create' }' on your form

Answer (score 0):

`root_path()` should return `/`

Comment: I understand that, but if I decide to change my root path in the future, I'd rather not have to go back and replace it with "products_path" everywhere in my application. But this will work fine if there isn't another way

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could redefine the `products_path` to be the same as `root_path` (like in a helper file):

```
def products_path(*params)
  root_path *params
end
```